# Is it possible to use Edge in mobile emulation?

Tags: java, selenium, mobile, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

Just I would like to ask is it possible?
I would like to use mobile emulation on EdgeDriver, but I don't know how. I am using Java and Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, the Microsoft Web Driver is available to download for Windows and MAC OS.

Reference:

[Microsoft WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

It cannot run on any mobile device. So currently, it is not possible to use mobile emulation on edge driver.

Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @szakika10 You don't need any reputation to accept the answer to your own question -- this is different than upvoting. There is a small greyed-out checkbox underneath the downvote button that you can click to accept the answer.

Comment: @szakika10 cc Christine you do, however, have to wait a period of time (typically a day or two) before you can accept an answer. This delay is intended to ensure people have equal opportunity to provide competing answers to a question.